# How can I record currently playing audio on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'd like to record what the iPhone is currently outputting. So I'm thinking about recording audio from Apps like Music (iPod), Skype, any Radio Streaming App, Phone, Instacast... I don't want to record my own audio or the mic input.

Is there an official way to do this? How do I do it?  It seems like `AVAudioRecorder` does not allow this, can somebody confirm?

Comment: I noticed that apps like [Shazam](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/shazam/id284993459?l=en&mt=8) can listen to the currently playing audio on your phone. That could mean you also could record it. Though I'm not sure if you just would record the speaker output via the microphone (which are naturally near to each other on an iPhone), or the actual audio track that gets routed to the speaker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Officially you can't. The audio stream belongs to the app playing it ,and iOS.

The Sandbox paradigm means that a resource owned by your App can't be used by another App. Resource here means Audio/Video stream or file. Exceptions are when a mediator like Document interaction controller are used.

If you want to do this you'd have to start with deducing AVFoundation's private methods and find out if theres a way there. Needless to say this it wouldn't be saleable on the App store and will probably only be possible on a jailbreak.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

This is only feasible only from time to time, as it's a time expensive process.

You can record the screen while listening your songs on Spotify, Music or whatever music application.
This will generate a video on your Photos application. That video can be converted on MP3 from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not true. The screen recordings will not actually have the audio from Apple Music at all, as it blocks it. Discord also uses this pipe as well, so you cannot record Discord audio either this way.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.